How can I find out if I need a transit visa travelling from Dominican Republic to Kenya?
I'm planning a trip from the Dominican Republic to Nairobi, Kenya, and I'm encountering some issues during the planning process.
I need to apply for a Kenyan eVisa (eTA), which requires providing trip information such as my hotel reservation, and details about my flights, including departure and arrival times. However, I'm not sure which flights to book because I'm uncertain about whether I need a transit visa for any of the countries I might pass through.
Can anyone provide insight into the transit visa requirements for these countries for a Dominican Republic / Haitian passport holder? How should I proceed with booking my flights and finalizing my trip details?
Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

" transit visa requirements for these countries" - what countries? There will be many potential routes. How can we know what countries you might pass through?

To research travel documentation and visa requirements I always start with two sources:

the IATA Travel Centre,  which provides personalised passport, visa and health requirements advice based on your personal details and itinerary.
the website of the airline(s) which offer suitable route(s) according to your budget, departure airport etc etc. For example, on British Airways there’s a Passports,visas and API section

If you’re looking at self-transfer transit options, remember that typically you may require documents to enter the transit country, not just transit.
Once you’ve narrowed down your options, check the official immigration website(s) of the relevant country(ies) too. Rules can change at short notice so if you’re booking well in advance I recommend you review them periodically in the run up to your departure date.

Unless the airline is really kind and willing to take the risk, if you do self-transfer, you do always need entry documentation just to board your flight
